# How can I define a standalone goal in Maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to define a completely standalone goal in my `pom.xml`, that can be invoked manually, like `mvn mygoal:mygoal`, that is never run automatically by any of the regular Maven phases. Is this possible to do in a pom file, or would I have to make a whole Maven plugin? (I'd prefer not to, if at all possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the `goal` - an action that the plugin can perform. So you have to make a plugin.

See also:

- [Basic Maven Concepts](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/start/concepts.html)
- [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle:Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins)
- [Guide to Developing Java Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)

Comment: Can I define new, independent tasks or phases without creating a plugin?

Comment: It's probably better to use a profile in that case @apennebaker